# Resizable divs within a div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, html, resizable

I need 3 divs which would span across the screen (100%, but that's not the main point) and be able to adjust their widths using mouse. The functionality I am trying to achieve is to be able to shrink the width of one div resulting in making another div wider.

I am thinking of using jQuery UI Resizable, but I couldn't find any examples of using that with multiple divs.

Any ides or links to examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should inspect the [jQuery Layout plugin](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/), doing exactly what you need and much more.

You could do what you need like this (not tested but should work) :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.layout.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('body').layout({ applyDefaultStyles: true });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-layout-center">Center</div>
<div class="ui-layout-east">East</div>
<div class="ui-layout-west">West</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does almost what I was looking for. Still, not exactly the functionality I needed, but I looked up a jQuery plugin jGrid which does the trick. Thanks for your time.

Comment: jGrid ? I thought it was a table-enhancer plugin.

Comment: Yeah, it actually is, I was mistaken by example where I saw the exact thing I needed. I am using your suggested UI.Layout, thanks.